# Regex replacement is not being performed on all matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone see why the following code does not perform the regex operations on all the {{ ... }} placeholders?  The input string below is just a stripped down version of the original.

https://jsfiddle.net/2L12jr3u/2/

```
var input = "{{ %1$@ }} / {{ %1$@ }} ({{ %2$@ }}) {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$d }} {{ %1$@ }} of {{ %2$d }} of {{ %3$d }}";

var regex = /(\{\{ \%(\d)\$(.) \}\})/g;

var match;
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    console.log(match);
    input = input.replace(match[0], '%@' + match[2]);
}

console.log(input);
```

Comment: What should the result look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `exec` to match multiple occurrences, in each iteration it starts searching from the [last matched index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Example:_Finding_successive_matches):

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property (test() will also advance the lastIndex property).

In your case it's much simpler and cleaner to use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```js
var input = "{{ %1$@ }} / {{ %1$@ }} ({{ %2$@ }}) {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$d }} {{ %1$@ }} of {{ %2$d }} of {{ %3$d }}";

var regex = /(\{\{ %(\d)\$(.) \}\})/g;

input = input.replace(regex, '%@$2');

alert(input);
```

Comment: I have to convert each of the different placeholder formatting strings with the js compatible version, so I need to match the different params.

Comment: at first glance I missed that the `$2` in `replace(regex, '%@$2')` was for the second match.  This works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you change the `input` variable while `exec` has not finished.
The index is moving forward, but the string gets shorter.

Add another variable, or wrap in a separate function, or use `replace` as suggested by @dfsq:

```js
var input = "{{ %1$@ }} / {{ %1$@ }} ({{ %2$@ }}) {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$d }} {{ %1$@ }} of {{ %2$d }} of {{ %3$d }}";

var regex = /(\{\{ \%(\d)\$(.) \}\})/g;
var output = input;
var match;

while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
    console.log(match);
    output = output.replace(match[1], '%@' + match[2]);
}

alert(output);
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense to why things were happening.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest to remove unnecessary groups in the regular expression,

`/\{\{ %(\d)\$. \}\}/g` instead of `/(\{\{ %(\d)\$(.) \}\})/g`.
Then, to replace you can use a much shorter approach (and also more clear in my oppinion):

```
var input = "{{ %1$@ }} / {{ %1$@ }} ({{ %2$@ }}) {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$@ }} {{ %1$d }} {{ %1$@ }} of {{ %2$d }} of {{ %3$d }}";
var output = input.replace(/\{\{ %(\d)\$. \}\}/g, "%@$1");
```

The final value of output is `%@1 / %@1 (%@2) %@1 %@1 %@1 %@1 of %@2 of %@3`

Comment: The additional groups are required, just not obvious in the shortened version of the string that I posted.